# Use of substr in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var MDI = '39.741679085941385';
var revMDI = "";
```

I am needing to modify the MDI value by removing the "." and all characters to the right of it.

I've tried this code and I'm getting a mozilla error:

```
var revMDI = MDI.substr(MDI,0,indexOf(MDI,'.'));
```

The error I'm getting is:

> org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function substr.

Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: The first argument to `substr()` should be `0`, not `MDI`.

Answer (score 4):

In other words, get the integer value.

```
var revMDI = parseInt(MDI);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `MDI.substring(0,MDI.indexOf('.'));`.

See the MDN Docs for [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Comment: Why would the error say `substr` if the problem is with `indexOf`?

Comment: Sorry, I noticed the second problem first. I edited my answer to include both.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just two characters:

```
var revMDI = MDI | 0;
```

The [bitwise OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR) `|` coerces MDI to a number and truncates it to `39`. And then the bitwise OR with `0` is the identity.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
var revMDI = MDI.substr(0, MDI.indexOf('.'));
```

But I would prefer [Scimonster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24374457/3187556) more.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it [`indexOf('.')`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf),

```
var MDI = '39.741679085941385';
var revMDI = MDI.substr(0, MDI.indexOf('.'));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Us5NN/)

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.  Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error.  I'm working in an IDE called Provenir and it apparently is pretty picky.  Thanks.

Comment: @Melinda Did you try the fiddle?

Comment: This is actually not going through the browser but through the Provenir IDE, would that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
revMDI = MDI.substr(0, MDI.indexOf('.'));
```

You have to declare the string you wish to modify with substr AND then with indexOf.

The way you were doing it kinda made no sense.